# Android get theme colors, disabled button

Tags: android, dynamic, colors, themes

Is there a way to read current theme colors from code ?

I want to 
1. Read disabled Button color and put it as EditText background
2. Read Spinner selected item color and put it as TextView background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Read disabled Button color and put it as EditText background

Disabled is not a color. It is a state of a `StateListDrawable` that is used for the button background. Hence, you cannot "read disabled Button color", because there is no simple color for "disabled".

> Read Spinner selected item color and put it as TextView background

The selected item in a `Spinner` has no specific color, as so therefore I have no idea what color you might mean here.

Comment: For Spinner - when I "open" spinner and see items, then when I press an item and hold, to keep it pressed - that item becomes blue in my case. My q is how to read that blue color, is it dependable on current theme ?

Comment: @Milan: Presumably, but I do not know for certain, as I have never investigated the inner workings of `Spinner` to that level. Sorry!